# android-support-v4.jar is not a valid zip

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a build path error I have not come across before:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Grbrbby's/Desktop/biz.midl/DebtCalculator/libs/android-support-v4.jar' in project 'DebtCalculator' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    DebtCalculator      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I haven't done anything to my physical files and this just started today. I've been able to build this previously.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

As a test, I did try and do a clean on it and it did not help.

Comment: I haven't had the ability to test the below answers. I restarted my eclipse and now it won't let me even import (or use my existing) project.

Answer (score 5):

Take the latest version of android-support-v4.jar. Inside your SDK go to this path. sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar and replace the one in your projects libs folder also if you have other dependencies make sure they have same android-support-v4.jar in their libs folder as well

Right click on this library, go to build path and select add to build path. It solved the problem in my case, hope its helpful for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your jar version by the most recent one.

Just select your project and click `Android Tools > Add Support Library`. This will update your jar to the most recent one.